# Configuring MikTeX on Ubuntu using command line

Tags: miktex, linux

I had a version of MikTex running on Ubuntu 16.04 that I updated, causing it to stop working. According to the official pages https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx the installation needs to be completed by running MiKTeX Console on GUI.

Is there a way to complete the installation using command line only? I do not have GUI access (my installation is on server used to support RStudio).

Comment: Do you really want to keep on MikTex? Have you ever considered moving to TeXLive?

Comment: I am considering TeXLive right now, as you can imagine. My only reason to stick with MikTeX is that I had it integrated with RStudio rather well, packages and all, and do not desire to go through the process again unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If MiKTeX stopped working after an update, I would recommend that you submit an issue. If you just want to finish the setup after a fresh installation, you can do it on the command line. Either

`miktexsetup finish`

if you want a private installation, or

`sudo miktexsetup --shared=yes finish`

if you want a shared (system-wide) installation.

Hope this helps.

(Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated the page you have referenced.)

Comment: Oh. Does this means the command line commands weren't there when the question was asked? (Side remark: Welcome).

Comment: Yes, the page (https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx) has been edited after the question was asked.